# Temporarily turn off redirects on all virtualhosts

Tags: redirects, apache2

Is there a configuration parameter I can set in the global configuration to disable redirects in all virtual hosts?

I've got a server with a bunch of virtual hosts with varying configurations, many of which are redirecting Letsencrypt acme-challenge requests.  This causes the Letsencrypt certification to fail.

Rather than going into each virtual host to disable the redirect, I'd like to configure apache2 to disable all redirects globally.

Comment: Sounds like a bandaid... not a fix. Take a look at `RewriteRule ^\.well-known\/acme-challenge\/ `.